# Relation between twisted and untwisted rational cohomology of non oriented manifold.

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, poincare-duality

If manifold is closed oriented, we have Poincare duality to relate homology and cohomology groups of manifold. My question is that what is the Relation between twisted and untwisted rational homology and cohomology of non oriented manifold(closed or open).

Comment: Look in Davis and Kirk, there is a duality between untwisted homology and twisted cohomology (and vice-versa). There is even a version with for manifold with boundary.

Comment: For closed non oriented case the theorem 5.7 of the book Lecture notes on algebraic topology by  Davis and Kirk works.  If you have some references  for open non oriented manifolds please share with me.